# Universal App QR code scanner?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, qr-code

I'm working on a BitCoin wallet for Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1, and am having some trouble with one aspect - sending coins.

Manually entering an address on a mobile device is tiresome, and as we have that perfect Bitcoin URI definition, which is used with QR codes all the time, it would be perfect for this purpose.

There is only one issue - WinRT has no QR code reader at the moment.

Yes, there is ZXing.Net, but even their WinRT sample lacks flexibility.

My question is - is there any ready-to-use solution for reading QR codes within an app on Windows Phone?

Comment: What do you mean it lacks flexibility, you just pass it a `writablebitmap` and it will tell if it can decode it or not.  What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is! I also had the same problem, and luckily found this, which at the moment seems to be the only way for real time barcode/qr code reading in Windows phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 Runtime apps. All you have to do is to install the NuGet package.
https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect#realtime-video-analysis-and-qr-code-detection

You can even find a working sample app here:
https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect/tree/master/VideoEffects/QrCodeDetector